# How to overwrite a CSV file in R?

Tags: r

I want to output a CSV file to a specified location. The code should overwrite the existing CSV file at the specified location each time the code runs.

I am getting an error saying :
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By default write.csv over writes the existing file, you need some thing else?

Comment: That error indicates that the 'path' to that file / folder does not exist. Double check your path name.

Comment: You may get that error if you currently have that file open. Make sure the original CSV is closed before you run the `write.csv`.

Comment: yeah. Actually the file was open. Thank you!

Comment: And you may not have writing permission to that file... in which case a warning message will also appear

Answer (score 2):

Probably your csv file is open. Close it and try again